# How do I get my button tag to call a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

Here, everything is working just fine. I only need my button tag to call the function which displays a random number on the p tag in DOM and not me refreshing the page all the time.[Here is my HTML][And here is my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHNRv.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtODL.jpg)

I tried using the  click

Also tried the inline method on my HTML but it's ignoring the call.

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: So where is the script tag in your HTML?

Comment: Also... Where in your code do you ever assign a click handler to an element?  You define a function, but then never do anything with that function.

Comment: I am sorry everyone, this is my first time asking question on here, I will do better next time. Meanwhile let go ahead and try your beautiful suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function in your script

```
function makerandom() {
document.getElementById("compscr").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
}
```

Also, add `onclick="makerandom()"` into your button in HTML
And add your script to tour html using the `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of tings you are missing before your code works. If I have to answer your question how do you get your button to call a function, then you need to go through some steps.

1. have the script/js code linked to your html first. I have added a script tag in the end of the body.
2. Add a listener to the `button` tag. eg. `<button id="click" onclick="randnum()">Play</button>`

```html
<head>
  <title>Guess right</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input id="userInput" type="number" />
    <p id="compscr"></p>
    <button id="click" onclick="randnum()">Play</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    let compscr = document.getElementById("compscr")
    let userInput = document.getElementById("userInput")
    let click = document.getElementById("click")

    const randnum = () => {
      document.getElementById("compscr").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      randnum();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```